# delete from nested select result problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

i have written this query:

```
delete from `test1` where id in (
SELECT id
FROM `test1`
GROUP BY m, n
HAVING count( id ) >1)
```

but mysql gives this error:

'You can't specify target table 'test1' for update in FROM clause '

why? how can i solve it?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating table while select is in progress... THat' not a piece of cake :-)
I would suggest to select into tmp table first, and do delete in second query.